# Quantile-Quantile Plot for Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution, qq-plot

I am performing regression analysis in R on count data which are negative binomial distributed. I would like to use a quantile-quantile plot as a tool to diagnose the fit of my models, but I am struggling to find an appropriate method for my data. A Normal Q-Q plot would not be appropriate since the residuals are not expected to be Normally distributed, so I think I need to compare my residuals against theoretical quantiles from the negative binomial distribution. I have tried using the 'qqPlot' function from the 'car' package, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: What are your residuals?  Usually such a model concerns the *conditional expectation* of the response distribution.  If you are, say, subtracting that from the observations, then you won't have anything remotely like a negative binomial distribution--you will have plenty of negative values.  If you are using deviance residuals, they won't even be integral and again cannot possibly have a negative binomial distribution.

Answer (score 6):

Normally distributed residuals can be generated using the randomized quantile residual method. For example

```
library(MASS)
fit <- glm(Days ~ .^4, family = negative.binomial(2), data = quine)
library(statmod)
res <- qresid(fit)
qqnorm(res)
qqline(res)
```

Here the MASS package provides the `negative.binomial` GLM family and the quine data example, while the `qresid` function is part of the statmod package.

Answer (score 0):

The package `performance` has this and other features for negative binomial regressions.

https://easystats.github.io/performance/

By using `check_model()` with the model, you will have several outputs that may help you understand the performance of your model.

Also, recently discovered `DHARMa` package, which uses a simulation-based approach to produce residuals plots. It works with complexed models (hierarchichal or mixed models) but, can also lead with negative-binomial ones. Take a look: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html